# Spring boot request X509 certificate on login page

Tags: java, spring, angular, apache, ssl

I am writing a **Spring Boot** application where on login page, user should be prompted to provide his **X509 certificate** (generated with my self-signed CA).
If user fails to provide certificate he is then shown another page with error. If user provides correct certificate, I want to show him a login page with his email pre-filled (read from certificate) and waiting for password input.
The only affected path should be **/admin/login** which requires certificate, all the other paths should be left completely unsecured.

What I have found so far is this procedure:

1. generate proper certificates
2. generate jks file
3. configure tomcat to ask for certificate
4. configure spring boot security
5. before loading login page, ask for certificate, parse it, check validity of data in it (common name,...)
6. show login page
7. check login data and if it is ok, do my stuff

I am having problem with points **3-5**, as all the tutorials I found are not really the solution I am looking for.

Also, later on, this Spring Boot project will run behind Apache's virtual host, so I guess I will need Apache to request certificate and then forward it to Spring Boot server.

I would need some starting points how to learn things I need to implement this.

---

*Some context:
I am building an Angular 6 (Spring Boot for backend) application, where I have two types of roles: users and admins.
Users will login through normal (Angular) page with only username and password. Admin will have to login by providing certificate and then logging in with username written in certificate and password - this will be done on separate page served by Spring Boot with Thymeleaf template engine.
What I envisioned to implement is that when user is authenticated I generate JWT token and save it to cookie, which will be used for all future request (for the duration of JWT's validity). The only problem is I don't know how to connect all of these things*

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  There is lots of stuff about this out there (e.g., https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security), but no comprehensive guide (that I can find) that covers every step.  Especially, how does one get a spring boot app to demand the client certificate?